# Subversion Server Using Active Directory

Tags: linux, svn, active-directory, ldap, centos

I am running a Linux server under VMWare Workstation 11 for subversion control. I also have a Windows Server 2012 R2 domain controller running under another VM. I am using CentOS7 and want to configure the authentication to use active directory. My CentOS7 server is already joined to the domain and I can perform tasks to verify I am connected such as.

```
$id myuser
```

I installed the mod_ldap and everything seems to be ok but when I go to the web site and try to authenticate I get the following message in the error log.

```
[Thu Mar 05 13:04:32.976448 2015] [auth_basic:error] [pid 2541] [client 
192.168.28.1:52099] AH01618: user myuser not found: /svn/testrepo
```

One thing I do not understand about this is that it is saying for client 192.168.28.1, when the DC is located at 192.168.28.3. Maybe something is wrong with that but I cannot figure out why it's showing the IP of the VMNet8 adapter.

Here is the information from my /etc/httpd/conf.d/svn.conf file.

```
<location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /svn
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Root Repo"
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Apache User,CN=Users,DC=corp,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
AuthLDAPBindPassword apachePassword
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://192.168.28.3.corp.mydomain.com:389/DC=corp,DC=mydomain,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
require valid-user
</location>
```

It seems no matter how I enter the credentials I always get the above error.

Comment: Just passing by: what is the reason to run AD-integrated server on Linux machine?

Comment: Because if I already have a Windows server why bother with user accounts on the Linux machine as well? I want to authenticate against their already existing AD credentials.

Comment: I mean -- why don't you install it on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually answered the problem myself. I had to change my LDAP url to the following.

```
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://192.168.28.3/DC=corp,DC=mydomain,DC=com?
AMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
```

I guess adding the domain onto the IP was a no go. I also had to add

AuthBasicProvider ldap

So now my file looks like the following.

```
<location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /svn
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthName "Root Repo"
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://192.168.28.3/DC=corp,DC=mydomain,DC=com?
sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Apache User,CN=Users,DC=corp,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
AuthLDAPBindPassword apacheUserPassword
Require valid-user
</location>
```